# How to create and call a auto populate text in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a requirement that i should create a order section form in Asp.net using C# and in that label called JOB DESCRIPTION and it should auto populate in textbox with description entered in Admin.config. Now my doubt is how should i create a Admin.config and how should i call it in asp.net after creating .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use External configuration files, i have used it to store connection string only, but i hope this can be useful in your case as well.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Other option, you can use resource file(.resx) in your project.
It simple stores static data in key-value pairs. Resource files best suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the structure for a .config file [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7w4sb0w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and access it programmatically [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c2kcht0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).